# Operador ? al escribir tipos de datos

Tags: c#

Tengo una curiosidad y quiero sacarme la duda, en que casos se declara una variable de la siguiente manera:

```
public short? Secuendia {get; set;}
```

Que quiere decir el signo de interrogación y en que casos el tipo de dato va acompañado con un carácter `?`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La declaración tipo `?` se utiliza cuando usas un tipo de dato que no puede ser `null` por ejemplo una Estructura y lo forzas a ser `null`, esto lo logras marcando con el operador `?`

A esto se le llama [Nullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Puedes checar mas aquí: [Operador ??](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

Diferencia contra una declaración normal

```
int a;
int? b;

a = 5;//ok
b = 5;//ok

a = null; //Error: Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nullable value type
b = null;//ok
```

Comment: jasilva, quieres decir que ? el tipo de dato no puede ser null y forzo hacer null? eso quiere decir que en mi base de datos va null o vacio?

Comment: @PedroÁvila "el tipo de dato no puede ser null" y lo forzamos a que pueda aceptar valores nulos, por ejemplo, en una base de datos estandar siempre existe la posibilidad de marcar campos que puedan aceptar valores nulos, asi que si tu tipo de datos en C# no acepta null, te generara un error y esto se cura facilmente usando `?`

Comment: Entendi gracias.

Answer (score 8):

El carácter `?` se usa en tipos de para indicar el valor es *nulleable*, osea que puede ser un numero valido o puede ser null.

Se conocen como [Nullable Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx), y pueden representar el rango normal de números del tipo especifico mas el valor null.

En la practica son instancias de la estructura `System.Nullable<T>` por lo tanto cuenta con algunos métodos.

Ejemplo:

```
int? num = null;

// tiene valor en num
if (num.HasValue)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("num = " + num.Value);
}
else
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("num = Null");
}
```

En booleanos sirve para respresentar valores *tristate* o de tres estados.

```
bool? tristate; // puede ser true, false o null
```